# How to change width of div with mouse?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component with input range. The width of grey area depends on input's value.
(I have a formula to calculate its width)

```
const del = (maxValue - minValue) / 1000;
const step = 100 / del;
const width = ((value - minValue) / 1000) * step;
return width;
```

[image]

And now it became necessary to make it so that I could change the width of the gray area with the mouse (and change the value for the input at the same time). Is it really possible to do this?

I need:

1. Change the width of the gray area with the mouse (how to do it? how to change the width of div with mouse?)
2. At the same time the value of the input range should changes (it means value depends on width of grey area)

So main question now is how to change the width of grey area with mouse in react?

Here what I have (short version)

Template:

```
 <div className="component">
            <div className="component-data">
                <div className="component-data-active" ref={ref}/>
            </div>
            <div className="component__range">
                <div className="component__range-wrapper">
                    <input
                        className="component__range-slider"
                        type="range"
                        max={maxValue}
                        min={minValue}
                        step={step}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                            setValue(event.target.value)
                            const progress = progressRef.current;
                            if (progress) {
                                const width = computeWidth(event.target.value);
                                progress.style.width = `${width}%`;
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                    <div ref={progressRef} className="component__range-progress"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Js:

```
    const ref = useRef();
    const progressRef = useRef(null);
    const [fillPercent, setFillPercent] = useState(50);

    const changeRangeFill = () => {
        const active = ref.current;
        active.style.maxWidth = fillPercent.toString() + '%'
    }

    const fillPercentData = () => {
        const width = computeWidth(value);
        setFillPercent(width);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const progress = progressRef.current;
        const width = computeWidth(value);
        progress.style.width = `${width}%`;
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        fillPercentData();
        changeRangeFill();
    }, [value, fillPercent])

    const computeWidth = (value) => {
        const del = (maxValue - minValue) / 1000;
        const step = 100 / del;
        const width = ((value - minValue) / 1000) * step;
        return width;
    }
```

Scss:

```
.component {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 2;

  &-data {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: 1px solid #EEF0F4;
    overflow: hidden;

    &-active {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 51%;
      background: #EEF0F4;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  }

  &__range {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    width: 100%;

    &-wrapper{
      position: relative;
    }

    &-slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 104%;
      height: 0;
      margin-left: -7px;
      background: none;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
      transition: opacity 0.2s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    &-slider:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    &-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-appearance: none !important;
      height: 14px;
      width: 14px;
      margin-top: -2px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: red;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    &-progress {
      position: absolute;
      content:'';
      width: 50%;
      height: 1px;
      background: red;
      top: 71%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code?

Comment: @JBrown I've added my code.